# Error with spinner

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, spinner

There is an error when i run my android program.

My Booking.java

```
package one.two;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Booking extends ListActivity
{
    private DBAdapter db; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        long id; 
        id = db.insertTime(
        new String("08:00")); 
        Cursor spinnerCursor = db.getSpinnerData(); 
        startManagingCursor(spinnerCursor);
        Spinner colourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        /*Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only the 'colourName' column in this case) */

        /*  String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_ARRIVAL}; 
        /* and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just the textView 'tvDBViewRow' from our new db_view_row.xml layout above) 
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.bookingtxt1};

         Now create a simple cursor adapter.. 
        SimpleCursorAdapter colourAdapter =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.booking, spinnerCursor, from, to);
        colourSpinner.setAdapter(colourAdapter);*/

    }

}
```

DBAdapter.java

```
    package one.two;


    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class DBAdapter {   
        private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/one.two/databases/"; 
        private static String DB_NAME = "irsyad";

        //values for the login table
        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "Username";
        public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
        public static final String KEY_LNAME = "LastName";
        public static final String KEY_FNAME ="FirstName";

        public static final String KEY_ROWID2 = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
        public static final String KEY_DESTINATION = "destination";
        public static final String KEY_ARRIVAL = "arrival";
        public static final String KEY_FERRY ="ferry";

        private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

        //declare Database name, tables names
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "irsyad";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "User";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_2 = "port";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        //declares the rules for the database tables
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table user (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "Username text not null, Password text not null,"
            + "LastName text not null, FirstName text not null);";

        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_2 =
            "create table port (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "status text not null, destination text not null,"
            + "arrival text not null, ferry text not null);";

        private final Context context; 

        private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase db;

        public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
            this.context = ctx;
            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }

        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            //Create the tables with the rules we set.
            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_2);
            }

            //OnUpgrade is only for use when u changed the database's version to 2 etc.
            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
            int newVersion) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                        + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS port");
                onCreate(db);
            }
        }    

        //---opens the database---
        public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
            db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        //---closes the database---    
        public void close() {
            DBHelper.close();
        }

        //Method for inserting login details, can be used in other java files when DBAdapter is
        //declared in the java file. e.g. DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        public long insertUser(String Username, String Password, String LastName, String FirstName) {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, Username);
            initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, Password);
            initialValues.put(KEY_LNAME, LastName);
            initialValues.put(KEY_FNAME, FirstName);
            return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }

        //---deletes a particular title---
        public boolean deleteUser(long rowId) {
            return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
                    "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
        }

        public long insertTime(String arrival) { 
           ContentValues initialValue = new ContentValues(); 
           initialValue.put(KEY_ARRIVAL, arrival); 
           return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_2, null, initialValue); 
        }
        //method for retrieving all the inputs from database
        public Cursor getAllUser() {
            return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID, 
                    KEY_USERNAME,
                    KEY_PASSWORD,
                    KEY_LNAME,
                    KEY_FNAME,},
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
        }   

        public Cursor getAllData() {
            return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_2, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID2, 
                    KEY_STATUS,
                    KEY_DESTINATION,
                    KEY_ARRIVAL,
                    KEY_FERRY,},
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
        }   

        //---retrieves a particular title---
        public Cursor getUser(long rowId) throws SQLException {
            Cursor mCursor =
                    db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                            KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_USERNAME, 
                            KEY_PASSWORD,
                            KEY_LNAME,
                            KEY_FNAME,}, 
                            KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                            null,
                            null, 
                            null, 
                            null, 
                            null);
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }

        public Cursor getSpinnerData() throws SQLException {
            Cursor mCursor =
                    db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_2, new String[] {               
                            KEY_ARRIVAL,}, 
                            null,
                            null, 
                            null, 
                            null, 
                            null);
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }

        //---updates a title---
        public boolean updateUser(long rowId, String Username, String Password, String LastName, String FirstName) {
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(KEY_USERNAME, Username);
            args.put(KEY_PASSWORD, Password);
            args.put(KEY_LNAME, LastName);
            args.put(KEY_FNAME, FirstName);
            return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                             KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
        }

        private boolean checkDataBase() {

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

            }
            catch(SQLiteException e) {
                //database does't exist yet.
            }

            if(checkDB != null) {
                checkDB.close();
            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if(dbExist) {
                //do nothing - database already exist
            }
            else {
                 db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
                 db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_2);

            }
        }
    }
```

Error log

```
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994): Error inserting arrival=08:00
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:66)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1313)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1173)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at one.two.DBAdapter.insertTime(DBAdapter.java:126)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at one.two.Booking.onCreate(Booking.java:22)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
08-29 07:01:55.966: ERROR/Database(994):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing :
     return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
by this :
     return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_USERNAME, initialValues);

I think I remember having trouble  passing null in the nullColumnHack paramater.

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't see the organization of your database. Look at the create statement of your database 2. You ask for "not null" on all field. And then you try to insert only an arrival with null to all the rest...